# What is the regex pattern for datetime (2008-09-01 12:35:45 )?

Tags: php, regex, datetime

What is the RegEx pattern for DateTime (2008-09-01 12:35:45 ) ?

I get this error:

> No ending delimiter '^' found

Using:

```
preg_match('(?n:^(?=\d)((?<day>31(?!(.0?[2469]|11))|30(?!.0?2)|29(?(.0?2)(?=.{3,4}(1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))|0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(?<sep>[/.-])(?<month>0?[1-9]|1[012])\2(?<year>(1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(?<time>((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(?i:\ [AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$)', '2008-09-01 12:35:45');
```

Gives this error:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0 in E:\www\index.php on line 19

Answer (score 91, accepted):

@Espo: I just have to say that regex is incredible. I'd hate to have to write the code that did something useful with the matches, such as if you wanted to actually find out what date and time the user typed.

It seems like Tom's solution would be more tenable, as it is about a zillion times simpler and with the addition of some parentheses you can easily get at the values the user typed:

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})
```

If you're using perl, then you can get the values out with something like this:

```
$year = $1;
$month = $2;
$day = $3;
$hour = $4;
$minute = $5;
$second = $6;
```

Other languages will have a similar capability. Note that you will need to make some minor mods to the regex if you want to accept values such as single-digit months.

Comment: Just a comment to say that this regex wont detect if the date, the month or the time has a value superior to the maximum one. For example 2012-65-65 99:99:99 will work. Apart from that the regex is great!

Comment: The regular expression shown is not intended to validate the date. It's intended to check the *syntax* of a string to see whether it looks like it could be a date. After getting the values out, you can validate the given date using normal date library functions.

Comment: This regex [will break in 7981 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_10,000_problem).

Comment: This regex gives a match even for a date like 2020-99-99 99:99:99 which is not right as mentioned by @darkheir

Answer (score 32):

A simple version that will work for the format mentioned, but not all the others as per @Espos:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})
```

Comment: plus one simplest solution!

Comment: This one validates both 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and 0000-00-00 00:00                       (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})?((:)?(\d{2}))

Answer (score 9):

http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=610

> ^(?=\d)(?:(?:31(?!.(?:0?[2469]|11))|(?:30|29)(?!.0?2)|29(?=.0?2.(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(?:\x20|$))|(?:2[0-8]|1\d|0?[1-9]))([-./])(?:1[012]|0?[1-9])\1(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d\d(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$

---

> This RE validates both dates and/or
>   times patterns. Days in Feb. are also
>   validated for Leap years. Dates: in
>   dd/mm/yyyy or d/m/yy format between
>   1/1/1600 - 31/12/9999. Leading zeroes
>   are optional. Date separators can be
>   either matching dashes(-), slashes(/)
>   or periods(.) Times: in the hh:MM:ss
>   AM/PM 12 hour format (12:00 AM -
>   11:59:59 PM) or hh:MM:ss military time
>   format (00:00:00 - 23:59:59). The 12
>   hour time format: 1) may have a
>   leading zero for the hour. 2) Minutes
>   and seconds are optional for the 12
>   hour format 3) AM or PM is required
>   and case sensitive. Military time 1)
>   must have a leading zero for all hours
>   less than 10. 2) Minutes are
>   manditory. 3) seconds are optional.
>   Datetimes: combination of the above
>   formats. A date first then a time
>   separated by a space. ex) dd/mm/yyyy
>   hh:MM:ss

---

**Edit**: Make sure you copy the RegEx from the regexlib.com website as StackOverflow sometimes removes/destroys special chars.

Comment: This answer provides a good regular expression, but not an answer for the actuall question. The question is to validate dates separated by "-" and not "/" as this answer describes.

Answer (score 6):

```
$date = "2014-04-01 12:00:00";

preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/',$date, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

$matches will be:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => 2014-04-01 12:00:00 
   [1] => 2014 
   [2] => 04 
   [3] => 01 
   [4] => 12 
   [5] => 00 
   [6] => 00
)
```

An easy way to break up a datetime formated string.

Answer (score 5):

```
^([2][0]\d{2}\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/([0-2]\d|[3][0-1]))$|^([2][0]\d{2}\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])\:[0-5]\d\:[0-5]\d)$
```

Comment: used this one with a slight modification allowing dates before 2000: "^(\d{4}-([0]\d|[1][0-2])-([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])\:[0-5]\d\:[0-5]\d)$"

Answer (score 3):

simple regex datetime with validation

```
^(\d{4})-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) ([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$
```

but it can't validation month which not include 31day (ex. 2022-11-31, 2022-02-30)

Answer (score 2):

regarding to Imran answer from Sep  1th 2008 at 12:33
there is a missing : in the pattern
the correct patterns are

```
preg_match('/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/', '2008-09-01 12:35:45', $m1);
print_r( $m1 );
preg_match('/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/', '2008-09-01 12:35:45', $m2);
print_r( $m2 );
preg_match('/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/', '2008-09-01 12:35:45', $m3);
print_r( $m3 );
```

this returns

```
Array ( [0] => 2008-09-01 12:35:45 )
Array ( [0] => 2008-09-01 12:35:45 )
Array ( [0] => 2008-09-01 12:35:45 )
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Greg Hewgill answer: if you want to be able to match both date-time and *only* date, you can make the "time" part of the regex optional:

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})( (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}))?
```

this way you will match both `2008-09-01 12:35:42` and `2008-09-01`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
/^(2[0-9]{3})-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0123])\:([012345][0-9])\:([012345][0-9])$/u
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the regex pattern from http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=610. The following pattern should match your case.

```
^(?=\d)(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d\d([-.\/])(?:1[012]|0?[1-9])\1(?:31(?<!.(?:0[2469]|11))|(?:30|29)(?<!.02)|29(?=.0?2.(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(?:\x20|$))|(?:2[0-8]|1\d|0?[1-9]))(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$
```

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: This one also match YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

This is my soloution:

```
[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP preg functions needs your regex to be wrapped with a delimiter character, which can be any character. You can't use this delimiter character without escaping inside the regex. This should work (here the delimiter character is /):

```
preg_match('/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/', '2008-09-01 12:35:45');

// or this, to allow matching 0:00:00 time too.
preg_match('/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/', '2008-09-01 12:35:45');
```

If you need to match lines that contain only datetime, add ^ and $ at the beginning and end of the regex.

```
preg_match('/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/', '2008-09-01 12:35:45');
```

[Link to PHP Manual's preg_match()](http://www.php.net/preg-match)

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution:

```
[12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]) ([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/39LWCacr76aGZfCN)

https://regex101.com/r/lbthaT/4

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simplified version (originated from Espo's answer). It checks the correctness of date (even leap year), and  hh:mm:ss is optional

 Examples that work:

- 31/12/2003 11:59:59

- 29-2-2004

```
^(?=\d)(?:(?:31(?!.(?:0?[2469]|11))|(?:30|29)(?!.0?2)|29(?=.0?2.(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(?:\x20|$))|(?:2[0-8]|1\d|0?[1-9]))([-./])(?:1[012]|0?[1-9])\1(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d\d(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))(|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$
```