# Check if a string contains date or not

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Given a string `"15:30:20"` and `"2011-09-02 15:30:20"`,
How can I dynamically check if a given string contains date or not?

```
"15:30:20" -> Not Valid

"2011-09-02 15:30:20" => Valid
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732/what-is-the-regex-pattern-for-datetime-2008-09-01-123545

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) Method.

```
string []format = new string []{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"};
string value = "2011-09-02 15:30:20";
DateTime datetime;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault  , out datetime))
   Console.WriteLine("Valid  : " + datetime);
else
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use

```
bool b = DateTime.TryParseExact("15:30:20", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal,out datetime);
```

To check if a string is parsable into DateTime.

Comment: If use above solution, my 2 samples will always show to true. I want to check if the string does not contains date then show false

Comment: That's assuming the date is ALWAYS going to be in that format. I wonder if that's what the OP wants

Comment: @RichK Good point, yet the OP states the inputs are strings, so I think my assumption is valid

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to check if string is date or not:

```
    private bool CheckDate(String date)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For dotnet core 2.0,

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("2017-09-02", "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out DateTime dtDateTime)
```