# HTML 5 Date Validation PHP

Tags: php, html, date

When using HTML5 date and you have `DD/MM/YYYY` is there a way to validate it using PHP so if `DD/MM/YYYY` has been left as `DD/MM/YYYY` it throughs an error?

I guess you cannot use `empty()` as its not empty.

Comment: A similar question has already been answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029769/php-function-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-date-regex

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  Are you referring to placeholders?  Are those even posted to the server?  Regardless of what's posted to the server, your server-side validation is the same it's always been.  If you're expecting a date, validate the input as a date.  The server-side code never had any guarantee that what's being posted was even handled by the intended HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 date inputs will send their value as `YYYY-mm-dd` format, but will *display* whatever format is locale-friendly to the user.

If nothing is entered (ie. the input is "blank"), then nothing is sent.

So, on the server, `empty` will work fine.

Comment: Note however that you still should validate it if it's *not* empty, because a malicious user could send an arbitrary value for the field.

Comment: @Yogu Well yes. Or an outdated browser will send anything the user types :p