# PHP get Datetime per preg_match

Tags: php, regex, datetime

I want to get the DateTime from a string in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.

To clearify: I'm getting a string from an API, by now the string looks like this:

```
{ts '2014-09-02 14:42:49'}
```

But the string could be changed, so I won't just shorten the string to only the `DateTime` That's why i want to receive it via a RegEx. Because then the string can change as much as it wants, as long as the Date Format stays the same  I'll always get the right result.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732/what-is-the-regex-pattern-for-datetime-2008-09-01-123545) with a solution and tried to use it for my case.
The RegEx is this:

```
$regEx = "(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})";
```

I also tried:

```
$regEx = "(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})";
```

It's working on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/39ei7), but I can't get it to work on my `PHP` code.

The whole code is this:

```
        $result = array();
        $regEx = "(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})";
        preg_match($details['date'], $regEx, $result);
        var_dump($result);
```

But the `var_dump` delivers an empty array.

How must i define the RegEx so it's working with `preg_match`?

Comment: Wow why would you write a regex for that? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php is more than enough

Comment: [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: Whenever something isn't working: enable `error_reporting`.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I edited my Question, it was unclear why i needed it

Comment: @mario i did, but no error was locked. I wouldn't ask a question before checking the error_log :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP regex needs `delimiters`, and also the order of the parameters of `preg_match` is wrong.

```
$regEx = '/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/';
preg_match($regEx, $details['date'], $result);
var_dump($result);
```

If `$details['date']` is just the datetime format string, you may consider using `DateTime` class instead.

```
$datetime = new DateTime($details['date']);
```

Comment: Thank you for that, never used RegEx before, purely beginner mistake by me. I clearified my Question, $details['date'] isn't just a datetime format string, but it contains one, that's why i wanted the RegEx!